# Store a matrix of elements that might be similar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, data-structures

I am making a small app in Ruby On Rails that let's you create RPG game maps like this:

[image]

To the question, "How should I save this data?", my first thought would be to create a Model `Tile` and a Model `Map`, which `has_many :tiles`. Probably giving an x and y parameter to `Tile`, to know where to locate them into the map.

But then again, I look at the map, and I see there are plenty of tiles that are exactly the same. For instance, the "grass tiles", which are repeated over and over in about 40% of the map.

So I was wondering. Is there any smarter way to save this information that may save me space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `TileType` model to store the "prototype" of a tile:

```
tile_types:
  name (String)
  id (Integer)
  sprite (String)
  travel_cost (Float)
  # ...
```

These could be created by the developers or trusted users.
And then use a join table (`tiles`) to link the actual tile instances to a map.

```
tiles:
  map_id (Integer, foreign key)
  tile_id (Integer, foreign key) # you may want an index on [map_id, tile_id]
  x (Integer, index) 
  y (Integer, index) # you may want an index on [x, y]
```

You would then use the join table with a [`has_many through:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship.

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tiles
  has_many :tile_types, through: :tiles
end

class Tile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :map
  belongs_to :tile_type

  # example of a geospatial query method
  def self.at(x:, y:)
    find_by(x: x, y: y)
  end
end

class TileType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :map_tiles
  has_many :maps, through: :tiles
end
```

Besides saving space it lets you tweak the game logic by editing the `tile_types` table. Say for instance you want to make moving through the Tall Grass tile slower:

```
TileType.find_by(name: 'Tall Grass').update(travel_cost: 1.8)
```

Otherwise you would have to find all the tiles belonging to every map and update them.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Dumb question. I knew that. -_- Deleteing the comment!

Comment: Why stating the relationship between `Map` and `TileType`?

Comment: Because at some point you will probably want to know which `TileType`s are used in a map. For example many map editors have a palette with the tiles in use. When you do `map.tile_types` rails will do the join query for you.

Comment: Indeed, Thanks mate. That was a great help